# ValueError: The truth value of a Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any()

Tags: python, streamlit, covariance-matrix

I am writing this code for streamlit deployment:

```
if show_covariance_matrix:
    if not cov_matrix.columns.empty:
        fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z=cov_matrix.values, x=cov_matrix.columns.tolist(), y=cov_matrix.index, colorscale='Viridis')
        st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

I want the covariance matrix to be interactive. But I get this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Index is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

`show_covariance_matrix` is defined as

```py
show_covariance_matrix = st.sidebar.checkbox("Show cov matrix")
```

This is the error traceback:

```
File "C:\Users\app.py",    line 556, in _run_script
    exec(code, module.__dict__)
File "C:\Users\app.py",    line 183, in <module>
    main()

File "C:\Users\app.py", line 50, in main
    fig = ff.create_annotated_heatmap(z=cov_matrix.values, x=cov_matrix.columns.tolist(), y=cov_matrix.index, colorscale='Viridis')

File "C:\Users\app.py", line 101, in create_annotated_heatmap
    validate_annotated_heatmap(z, x, y, annotation_text)

File "C:\Users\app.py",   line 41, in validate_annotated_heatmap
    if y:

File "C:\Users\app.py",   line 2809, in __nonzero__
    raise ValueError(
```

I have tried reworking with the code but it did not fix it.

Comment: Not enough details. How is `show_covariance_matrix` defined? What's the full trackback? etc.

Comment: Probably `show_covariance_matrix` is returning a pandas Series, so using it with `if` throws that error. Without details, we can only guess though.

Comment: I think you need `y=cov_matrix.index.tolist()` just like you did on the `x` parameter. The API is likely just interested in whether there is anything line the list, but indexes don't work that way on boolean tests.

Comment: Hint: where the code says `cov_matrix.columns.tolist()`, what was the purpose of the `.tolist()` part? Would it have worked without that? Why not? Do you see why similar logic might apply to the `y` value, as for the `x`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`create_annotated_heatmap` tries to check whether a `y` value was provided to it, using `if y:`. This makes sense for most sorts of inputs, such as lists. However, it [will not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951) for an `Index` (or `Series`, or `DataFrame`, [or a Numpy `array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/)), because of special protections built in to those types.

Convert the Index to a list first - just as with the `x` parameter.